# How can I select a cell in a UITable by clicking a corresponding plotted point in a figure?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-app-designer, matlab-uitable

I have a UITable storing 2d points and three pieces of data for each point. I have plotted the 2d portion of the data from this table in a figure.

What I need to do is select the row of the table that corresponds to a clicked point. For example: if I click the point [5,-6], then the selected cell should jump to a row with matching 'X' and 'Y' values (specifically the second column of data if possible).

I have been banging my head against this for a few hours now because I can't find a way to pass any data in or out.

Any help would be *much* appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which bit of this are you struggling with? Getting the click event, identifying the data a click event corresponds to, programmatically highlighting the table, etc? Currently this is quite broad...

Comment: I am having trouble connecting the bits together. I can highlight a cell in the table, I can get a click event, and I can identify which point was closest to the click, but I can't get the pieces to communicate to each other in the way they need to.

Essentially, I don't know how to pass the table as an argument to the click handler, or get the cell highlighted from within the click handler.

Sorry if I wasn't clear before, and thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Are you using App Designer?

Comment: Yes, I am using App Designer. I would have just made a member function otherwise, but it doesn't seem to like that. XD